# Trigger firebase cloud function at a specific time

Tags: android, firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions

I want a firebase cloud function to trigger at a specific time. This time is stored in the cloud Firestore as a document field. After googling I find that I can schedule the function using ***cron-job*** or use firebase ***cloud schedular*** but for this I need to know the time at which I need to schedule the function which is not possible because time is dynamically generated by the user. Even if I know the time I will have to schedule it manually which is not practical. And if I will schedule the function to trigger too frequently(like every 5 minutes) and check if any time is stored in the database in 5 minutes range then it would require a lot of cloud resources(read,write,cpu time) and I might exceed the free limit. So is there any way to do this without Blaze plan of firebase?

Comment: The way to do this is with Cloud Tasks, which requires a payment plan. https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Comment: @DougStevenson so there is no way I can implement it using the free plan?

Comment: Did you manage to pull this off? I have a similar requirement

Comment: Hello, I store start and stop time in firebase data in milli format, so I want to execute cloud function when time reach scheduled time and trigger when time reach stop time.